# Whats the best way to orchastrate multiple google API clients?

Tags: java, oop, google-api

I am new to Java and I think I'm at a little learning curve in my understanding.

I have a project which consists of 3 google API clients in 3 separate files. I would like a way to pull the results of each API into one instance and use the results of one to dynamically change the parameters of another.

for example:

`ActivityRecognitionAPI` - give me if the device is `WALKING`, `RUNNING` etc

`GeoFencingAPI` - lets me create a geofence around a location...

How would I use the result of walking, to change the size of the geofence?

This is all in the context of an Android app and I'd appreciate any references to things I should read / try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you have multiple clients. You want to call these clients and use results of these calls.

My suggestion to you is to create a class encapsulating these clients:

```
    class GeoFence{

        private ActivityRecognition activityRecognition;
        private GeoFencing geoFencing;

        public GeoFence(ActivityRecognition activityRecognition, GeoFencing geoFencing) {
            this.activityRecognition = activityRecognition;
            this.geoFencing = geoFencing;
        }
    }
```

Then add a method representing the action that you want to perform with a pseudo-code describing what you need the method to do:

```
        public void addGeoFence() {
            // get current activity type (call activityRecognition API)
            // add geo fence given the current activity (call activityRecognition API)
        }
```

Now, you are ready to implement the method.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to Java and this was a very clear answer

Comment: @Alex I am glad it helped.